# Pytest Flask, error 308 Permanent Redirect when login

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I want to try my app, here is the test code :

```
import sys
import pytest
from flask_simplelogin import SimpleLogin

sys.path.insert(1, '')
from app import app as myapp


#---------------------------------------------------
#SETUP
#---------------------------------------------------

myapp.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'something-secret'
myapp.config['SIMPLELOGIN_USERNAME'] = 'admin'
myapp.config['SIMPLELOGIN_PASSWORD'] = 'secret'
SimpleLogin(myapp)

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    return myapp

@pytest.fixture
def setup_url():
    return "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"

def login(client):
    return client.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login", data=dict(
        username="admin",
        password="secret"
    ))

#---------------------------------------------------
#TESTS
#---------------------------------------------------

def test_get_list_campagne(client,setup_url):
    resp = login(client)
    assert resp.status_code==200

    resp = client.get("/Campagne")
    assert resp.status_code==200
```

But it returns a permanent redirection, so i tried with the attribute "follow_redirects=True" :

```
def login(client):
    return client.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login", data=dict(
        username="admin",
        password="taleinfo"
    ), follow_redirects=True)
```

But i think it is just a way to get around the problem, i don't think i'm logged after that.

here the error :
E       AssertionError: assert 308 == 200
E        +  where 308 = < 263 bytes [308 PERMANENT REDIRECT]>.status_code

I do not found any similar problem.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 24):

Had the same problem I solved it by adding a Slash `/`

try this code:

```
def login(client):
return client.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/", data=dict(
    username="admin",
    password="secret"
))
```

as you can see add the Slash in the login/ like that. it sounds stupid I know but give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Why this is not an accepted answer even with many upvotes?

Comment: @Sam In my opinion, because although it indeed works, it does not provide an explanation for the solution. It's a nice workaround/quickfix that I am actually using myself, but it does not express deep understanding of the root cause of this behavior.

Comment: I ran into this as well. The reason for the redirect has to do with matching the route that was added. If you add a route with a trailing slash (/), then only calls using that trailing slash will match the route. Calls without the slash get matched to a 308 redirect that is automatically created when you create a route with a trailing slash. If you create the route without the trailing slash, no 308 redirect is created with a trailing slash to your non-trailing slash route. Calls with a trailing slash to a non-trailing slash route return a 404.

Answer (score 2):

I got this same error as a result of having two slashes in my path. It was something like:

```py
def test_my_annoying_failing_test(client):
   response = client.post('/api//my_path/to-somewhere') # notice the double slash
   # ...test continues here..
```

Changing that double slash to a single slash fixed it for me:

```py
def test_my_annoying_failing_test(client):
   response = client.post('/api/my_path/to-somewhere')
   # ...test continues here..
```

I am not sure what the root cause of that issue is though.